# File.Exists() returns false in C#

Tags: c#, .net

This is weird. The file is already exists, but I am still getting false when using File.Exist(path):

```
string path = @"‪D:\Design\SVG\black_circle.svg";
```

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I also tried the equivalent function in Python:

```
os.path.isfile(r"D:\Design\SVG\black_circle.svg")
//output -- True
```

And this screenshot shows the file system.

[image: Screenshot of FileSystem]

What makes `File.Exists()` return false?

Comment: I don't believe you. Prove that file exists really

Comment: So you're saying that the new screenshot represents the actual situation, and that both your C# code and your Python code are looking for an SVG file, and C# says it's not there and Python says it is?  And you've verified that the file is actually there on disk?

Comment: @user3380608: what do you want from us, how could we help you? We don't know if the file really exists and you haven't shown any code which we could have a look at.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want to know why `File.Exists()` returning false while the file is there

Comment: Could be a permission problem.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266637/why-system-io-file-existsstring-path-returns-false) will help you.

Comment: Is the file on a server, or another computer? Is the file on the same hard drive as the program?

Comment: @DrewKennedy it on in same computer and the same hard drive

Comment: @Gopichandar Thanks, but the permission is fine for the file, even though if it is permission problem why python code was able to find the file while c# code couldn't?

Comment: FWIW, [this is the guts](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,56cd161c65ab07fe) of what's going on, showing it needing to be able to _read_ the file as per @Gopichandar's comment, rather than it just needing to check if it is there.  Try following Jon Skeet's suggestion in the linked question and perform a read on it to get further error information.

Comment: Could it be: The file is on a drive mapped to `D:\` for the current user, but you are running Visual Studio as an Administrator, therefore the drive is not mapped when debugging?

Comment: Have you doubled backslashes \\ in 'path'?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I got **NotSupportedException**, _the givin path's format is not supported_

Comment: What _exactly_ is `path` set to?

Comment: @user3380608: maybe it would help  if you showed also the path the you have used in C#.

Comment: The path in c# code `string path = @"‪D:\Design\SVG\black_circle.svg";`

Comment: I can't reproduce what it is you're seeing, and if your permissions are indeed fine, then I have no idea what exactly is going on. Something in the background is preventing your program from accessing the file. Try executing `if(Directory.Exists(@"D:\Design\SVG\")) {...}` and see what the result is.

Comment: I can certainly reproduce the thing I mentioned above: Can see a file when running from Visual Studio WITHOUT elevated permissions, but can't see the same file with the same code when running from Visual Studio WITH elevated permissions.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I solved this issue, it is not related to permissions, if the path copied from the explorer to visual studio, then I won't be able to read the file, but if I wrote it in visual studio then it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in an [answer to Stack Overflow question *What is causing NotSupportedException (“The given path's format is not supported”) while using a valid path?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856821/what-is-causing-notsupportedexception-the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported/24856870#24856870).

If I used the path which is directly copied from Windows Explorer, C# wouldn't be able to read the file, and the `IndexOf(':')` will be 2, but if wrote the path in Visual Studio it would work fine and `IndexOf(':')` will be 1.

```
string copiedPath = @"?D:\Design\SVG\black_circle.svg";
int a = copiedPath.IndexOf(':')  //output 2
string hardCodedpath = @"D:\Design\SVG\black_circle.svg";
int i = hardCodedpath .IndexOf(':'); //output 1
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  Why would `copiedPath` ever have a question mark in it, and why would that throw off the number of times `':'` appears?  You said you did `string path = @"‪D:\Design\SVG\black_circle.svg";` then `if (!File.Exists(path)) { throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found"); }`  Something doesn't sound right, here.

Answer (score 0):

This code correctly detects the file existence.

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE");
if (f.Exists) 
   {
    ... do something; 
   }
```