# Files not being found

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, stanford-nlp

My project is not finding files that definitely exist. I am using the Stanford NLP library and was getting file not found exceptions which I began debugging.

Here is my test code:

```
String jarRoot = @"stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31\stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31\stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models\edu\stanford\nlp\models\pos-tagger\english-left3words\";
foreach (String fName in Directory.GetFiles(jarRoot))
{
    Console.WriteLine("File in jarRoot: " + fName);
    Console.WriteLine("File exists? " + File.Exists(fName));
}
```

The output:

```
File in jarRoot: stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31\stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31\stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models\edu\stanford\nlp\models\pos-tagger\english-left3words\english-left3words-distsim.tagger
File exists? False
File in jarRoot: stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31\stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31\stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models\edu\stanford\nlp\models\pos-tagger\english-left3words\english-left3words-distsim.tagger.props
File exists? False
```

How could File.Exists() possibly be returning false?

Screenshots of directory:
[image]

Comment: jar root is not a correct physical path please make sure the path is correct.

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI It's a perfectly valid path, not sure what you mean.

Comment: First try open run command and run this path if it is valid there will be no error.

Comment: @PatrickHofman The file paths are being emitted by `Directory.GetFiles()`, so it appears they *do* exist. I'd wager it's a permissions problem.

Comment: The files are in my bin/Debug directory. The files are being found with Directory.GetFiles() but aren't being recognized.

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI The path is *clearly* valid because `Directory.GetFiles()` is returning files.

Comment: @Rob thank you. I don't know why I got -1 for asking. The files are being found but also aren't. It's a difficult question to ask and I tested long before posting the question. I just tried running visual studio as administrator but that didn't seem to work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You really need to show more. Where are the files located? What are the permissions. From where that code is running?

Comment: @Rob may be right, from this link [Why does System.IO.File.Exists(string path) return false?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18266662/6741868), the answer below it suggests trying `Console.WriteLine("File exists? " + File.Exists(Server.MapPath(string path)));`

Comment: Try run program as Admin.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I added a screenshot of the folder but I'm not sure if that helps. The 2 files are there. They are in the bin/Debug folder nested a few folders deep.

Comment: In cases of file system (or registry) not doing what I expect I turn to [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/processmonitor) to see the details of the underlying Win32 API call.

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI just tried running the .exe in the bin/Debug folder as admin but it still returns false.

Comment: I recently installed MalwareBytes on this computer a few days ago. Could that be the culprit? I just closed it and File.Exists() is still returning false.

Comment: See this question for possible causes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266637/why-does-system-io-file-existsstring-path-return-false

Comment: Can you please show the path of file inside foreach loop ?

Comment: First insert this code   string extension = Path.GetExtension(fName); inside foreach loop then test the output in extension.I think the file extension is not recognizable.

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI the relative path is in there already. Environment.CurrentDirectory returns "E:\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug"

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI Please stop spamming this post with unrelated remarks. They are not helpful.

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI Path.GetExtension() returned the extensions correctly. Something is really wrong here...

Comment: @Abbas That link solved the problem. Opening it as a FileStream gave me a more detailed error. Surely enough: System.IO.PathTooLongException was thrown. I'm going to post the answer now. Thanks so much everyone!

Comment: it seems like the path is very long, could it be that it exceeds the allowed 255 characters?

Comment: @ThFl that was exactly the problem. File.Exists() simply returns false and doesn't throw an exception if the path is too long.

Comment: @blagh alright, I wasn't sure whether the solution could be this simple because I thought it would definitely throw an exception if so. Glad to know your problem is fixed however.

Answer (score 2):

This was sorted out in the comments of the question. Opening the file using a FileStream threw a 'System.IO.PathTooLongException' exception. File.Exists() simply returns false if it encounters any errors such as file path being too long.

@Abbas provided this link that fixed the issue and may be helpful:
[Why does System.IO.File.Exists(string path) return false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266637/why-does-system-io-file-existsstring-path-return-false)

Thanks everyone!