# Any reliable method that provides info about file redirection?

Tags: c#, .net

All the C# methods to access a file, e.g. FileInfo(), FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(), FileStream(), etc can be misleading when run in WOW64 mode, i.e. the app is compiled as x86 but run on x64. You can have totally different files with the same name in \Windows\System32\ and \Windows\SysWOW64\, or have no file in \Windows\System32\, but when your code tries to access it in \Windows\System32\ then the file copy in \Windows\SysWOW64\ will be used with no indication that the redirection took place. Is there any method that would indicate such redirection, for any reason (WOW64 or other)? The brute force is to check for WOW64 execution and check the path for \Windows\System32\
but I would prefer the system handle it for me. Also there could be some other special cases.

Comment: You know SysWOW64 redirection is being used when you run a 32-bit process on a 64-bit Windows.

Comment: So what is your point? The question already explains it

Comment: What is your question, then? It seems your question already answers your questiion, if i interpret your comment correctly. You asked "_Is there any method that would indicate such redirection_", and i told you in my comment how you would identify whether such a redirection is active for the process at hand, which your comment then said is already explained in your question...

Comment: If you try to get some info about a file by using FileInfo but this FileInfo returns info about totally different file then you would like to get some indication about it, wouldn't you? I do not want to have indication that such redirection can take place. I want an indication that such redirection actually took place?

Comment: I am not sure what you are really trying to ask. I guess you are trying to ask: "_How do i access files in the real, native System32 folder on a 64-bit Windows OS from a 32-bit process_"? Is that your question? Please confirm.

Comment: Maybe try to read the question again. In some cases, your app does not need the transparency when accessing a file. It needs specific info if the requested file  is used and not another copy

Comment: That's funny. I read the title, it says, "_... provides info about file redirection?_" I read your question, it says "_Is there any method that would indicate such redirection_", i read your comment that there says "_I want an indication that such redirection actually took place_". Maybe, just maybe, it is you yourself who should read the stuff you wrote. Just sayin...

Answer (score 1):

You can disable file system redirection with [Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64disablewow64fsredirection)

For example =>

```
bool bWow64 = false;
IsWow64Process(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, out bWow64);
if (bWow64)
{
    IntPtr OldValue = IntPtr.Zero;
    bool bRet = Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(out OldValue);
}
```

With :

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool IsWow64Process(IntPtr hProcess, out bool Wow64Process);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(out IntPtr OldValue);
```

Comment: Thanks, this disabling seems to work for methods like FileInfo. I still have to try for others like ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom()